Super Challenging Dataset Manipulation
I'm trying to manipulate my input output (IO) tables as follows.
Suppose we have an IO table with 2 countries and 4 industries:
df=data.frame(industry=c("DEU_10T12","DEU_13T15","DEU_16","DEU_17","ITA_10T12",
"ITA_13T15","ITA_16","ITA_17"),DEU_10T12=c(20,24,26,20,10,0,NA,1.5),
DEU_13T15=c(15,16,4.5,NA,7.5,5,3,0),DEU_16=c(1.5,6,4,0,0.5,15,3,0.5),
DEU_17=c(NA,20,10,2,0,0,0,7), ITA_10T12=c(0.5,2,3,4,10,50,2,15),
ITA_13T15=c(25,0,4.5,NA,17.5,5,13,0.9), ITA_16=c(2,3,40,20,0.5,15,3,1),
ITA_17=c(1,9,0.5,2,10,20,50,7))

The objective is to create the following dataset where I now have 3 sectors and the new one is the sum of sectors 16 and 17
df2=data.frame(industry=c("DEU_10T12","DEU_13T15","DEU_16T17","ITA_10T12","ITA_13T15","ITA_16T17"),
DEU_10T12=c(20,24,46,10,0,1.5),DEU_13T15=c(15,16,4.5,7.5,5,3),DEU_16T17=c(1.5,26,16,0.5,15,10.5),
ITA_10T12=c(0.5,2,7,10,50,17),ITA_13T15=c(25,0,4.5,17.5,5,13.9), ITA_16T17=c(3,12,62.5,10.5,35,61))

Here, I'm aggregating sectors 16 and 17 into a new sector 16T17.
It seems impossible to have a code for a such complex manipulation. Any help with it? I don't know how to accomplish this.
Thanks!
*** UPDATE ***
Code attempt:
# Aggregate sectors 16 and 17 (naively and still does not work, and not efficient since I have 100 countries and 10 sectors in my original dataset)
df$DEU_16T17 = rowSums(df[, c("DEU_16", "DEU_17")], na.rm = TRUE)
df$ITA_16T17 = rowSums(df[, c("ITA_16", "ITA_17")], na.rm = TRUE)
# Remove individual sector columns
df2 = df[, !grepl("DEU_16|DEU_17|ITA_16|ITA_17", names(df))]

To make things more clear. The aggregation objective is the following:
When a new row labeled DEU_16T17 is created, it matches the content of the second column DEU_10T12 by adding the values of DEU_16 and DEU_17 from the corresponding rows. Similarly, for the newly created row ITA_16T17, it equals the sum of ITA_16 and ITA_17 in the second column.
The complexity arises when encountering the newly created column DEU_16T17 (e.g. for DEU). In this case, the first row labeled DEU_10T12 in this column matches the values found in both DEU_16 and DEU_17 columns at their respective first entries. Additionally, the content of the row DEU_16T17 in the DEU_16T17 column equals the sum of the values from DEU_16 and DEU_17 in correspondence with row DEU_16, and also equals the sum of the values from DEU_16 and DEU_17 corresponding to row DEU_17.

It seems bold to describe this as super challenging without laying out what you've tried and where these super challenges came in.   Stack Overflow is not a coding service.  Can you specify the algorithm used to aggregate these columns?  is it just literal addition?

From your dput we can see you have quotes around your NA values so they are character class "NA" rather than numeric class missing values NA. This makes any columns of your data frame that have "NA" values characeter class and not numeric, which will cause problems when you try to do mathematical operations like +. I would suggest correcting your classes before making any further attempts.

I'm aware that there is not a coding service, but you are right. Let me add my code attempt

The attempt code looks like a good start - you have the same names in your "Industry" column as across the other column titles - are those rows to be dropped or also aggregated somehow?

That's correct, I have the same names in my "Industry" column as across the other column titles. The table is a mirror, the first row name corresponds to the second column name, the second row name corresponds to the third column name, and so on. Let me clarify the aggregation objective in the main question. Thanks

The tidyverse is good for operations like these. I think the best way is to put the data into long form with tidyr::pivot_longer(). You can then find all industries ending in "_16" or "_17" and replace the suffix with "_16T17" using dplyr::mutate(across()). This makes it easy to group by industry and sum the relevant value. After this we can put the data back into wide form.
library(dplyr)

df |> 
    # They're character types in your sample data
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE) |>
    tidyr::pivot_longer(
        -industry,
        names_to = "industry_col"
    ) |>
    # Rename 16 and 17 industries so they can be aggregated
    mutate(across(industry:industry_col, \(x) if_else(
        grepl("_1[67]$", x), gsub("_1[67]$", "_16T17", x),
        x
    ))) |>
    # Sum the values we have given the same names
    summarise(
        value = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE),
        .by = c(industry, industry_col)
    ) |>
    # Put back into wide form
    tidyr::pivot_wider(
        names_from = industry_col
    ) 

# # A tibble: 6 × 7
#   industry  DEU_10T12 DEU_13T15 DEU_16T17 ITA_10T12 ITA_13T15 ITA_16T17
#   <chr>         <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1 DEU_10T12      20        15         1.5       0.5      25         3  
# 2 DEU_13T15      24        16        26         2         0        12  
# 3 DEU_16T17      46         4.5      16         7         4.5      62.5
# 4 ITA_10T12      10         7.5       0.5      10        17.5      10.5
# 5 ITA_13T15       0         5        15        50         5        35  
# 6 ITA_16T17       1.5       3        10.5      17        13.9      61  


Fantastic! Thank you very much. I'll proceed to implement the code in my dataset, and once I've done that, I'll get back to confirm your question.

@Maximilian your comment was posted after my edit so probably you're using the current version but make sure you do - I realised it wasn't handling NA properly.

This is probably overkill, but to make this less hard coded, we could do the following approach.
> df[is.na(df)] <- 0
> pnms <- \(sn) {
+   Map(paste0, lapply(sn, `[`, 1), 'T', sub('.*_', '', sapply(sn, `[`, 2)))
+ }
> idcol <- 'industry'
> ## row operations
> sf <- split(df, {
+   di <- nchar(df[[idcol]])
+   with(rle(di < max(di)), 
+        rep(replace(values, values, cumsum(values[values])), lengths))
+ })
> res <- sf[1] |> c(
+   sapply(sf[-1], \(x) tapply(x[-1], substr(x[[1]], 1, 2), colSums)) |> 
+     Map(f=c, lapply(sf[-1], `[`, 1) |> lapply(pnms)) |> lapply(as.data.frame)
+ ) |> do.call(what='rbind')
> ## col operations
> sf <- Map(`[`, list(res), split(names(res), nchar(names(res)))) 
> sn <- split(names(sf[[1]]), substr(names(sf[[1]]), 1, 3))
> sf[[1]] <- Map(`[`, list(sf[[1]]), sn) |> 
+   lapply(rowSums) |> do.call(what='data.frame') |> 
+   setNames(pnms(sn))
> res <- sf |> do.call(what='cbind') |> 
+   {\(.) with(., .[order(industry),
+                   c(idcol, sort(setdiff(names(.), idcol)))])}() |> 
+   `rownames<-`(NULL)
> res
   industry DEU_10T12 DEU_13T15 DEU_16T17 ITA_10T12 ITA_13T15 ITA_16T17
1 DEU_10T12      20.0      15.0       1.5       0.5      25.0       3.0
2 DEU_13T15      24.0      16.0      26.0       2.0       0.0      12.0
3 DEU_16T17      46.0       4.5      16.0       7.0       4.5      62.5
4 ITA_10T12      10.0       7.5       0.5      10.0      17.5      10.5
5 ITA_13T15       0.0       5.0      15.0      50.0       5.0      35.0
6 ITA_16T17       1.5       3.0      10.5      17.0      13.9      61.0
> stopifnot(all.equal(df2, res))

